# Sort Chart In Descending Order

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Wondering if it was possible to sort chart data display in descending order :

[image]

I've no Idea of how to do so.

The only thing I know is how to browse series values :

```
Set s = cht.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    For i = 1 To s.Points.Count
        If s.Values(i) < 0 Then 'JustAnExample
            'WhateverIwant
        End If
    Next i
```

In addition, the above chart is built with data from a worksheet :

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help starting [Excel to sort from highest to lowest](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-a-bar-graph-on-Excel-to-sort-from-highest-to-lowest)

Comment: Is the chart in discussion build using VBA? Do you try processing an existing chart? Should the chart be linked to a range and dynamic? I mean, if one of the involved values increases, to resort the data? In principle, chart can be created using an array. So the involved range can be placed in an array, sorted and feed the chart series with the sorted array. If dynamic, the function doing that should be associated to the Change event, and so on. But, in order to supply a solution, I must know more. And I will leave my office in about 15 minutes...

Comment: If the situation is not clarified in this (short) available time, I can do something only after I will be at home. In some hours... If not something confidential and you can send the used workbook on my personal mail (in my profile), but **explaining what is to be done**, I can try helping when being available.

Comment: You did not answer my specific clarification questions... Should I understand that the chart is manually created and should be identified (should it have a specific  name) and pseudo sort (some) values. Since you do not show the axes values, I try deducing which row is used in x/y... When say 'static', should this mean that the values on the range will never be changed? Now I close my laptop and leave my office

Comment: @FaneDuru I edited again. (Note that it is a stacked column chart). The chart is created by a macro and before creating chart, the table with data `Name1,Name2...` is created. After creating the chart, I wish to order my chart in descending order

Comment: Post the creation code. I will try adapting to sort before setting its series... I am driving now.

Comment: @FaneDuru Have a safe drive, I will edit my post ASAP

Comment: You did not post your actual code to create the chart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next solution. Since you did not post your chart creation code, I imagined something doing that:

```
Sub createStackedColChart_Arrays()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr1, arr2, arrN, arrD
 Dim chartName As String, arrSort, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 chartName = "MyChartSorted"
 arr1 = sh.Range("A2:D2").value 'first series array
 arr2 = sh.Range("A3:D3").value 'second series array
 arrN = sh.Range("A1:D1").value 'X axes values array

 'Create the reference array of summarized values per column:
 ReDim arrSort(1 To UBound(arr1, 2))
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
      arrSort(i) = arr1(1, i) + CLng(arr2(1, i))
 Next i
 '_______________________________________________

 'sort arrays according to reference one (arrSort):
 sortArrs arrSort, arrN, arr1, arr2 

 'if the (testing) chart exists, delete it:
 On Error Resume Next
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Delete
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 'create the necessary chart:
 With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=100, width:=375, top:=75, height:=225).Chart
    .Parent.Name = chartName                  'name it to have a reference when delete it
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr1 'add first series
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = arr2 'add first series
    .HasTitle = True                          'set it to allow a Title
    .chartTitle.text = "My Sorted Chart"      'set the Title
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked              'set the chart type
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = arrN       'add values to X axis
 End With
End Sub

Sub sortArrs(arrS, arrN, arr1, arr2) 'being passed byRef, the initial arrays are filtered
    Dim i As Long, nxtEl As Long, tmp, tmpN, tmp1, tmp2
    For i = LBound(arrS) To UBound(arrS) - 1 'iterate between the arrS elements (except the last):
        For nxtEl = i + 1 To UBound(arrS)    'iterate between the arrS elements (starting from the second one):
            If arrS(i) < arrS(nxtEl) Then    'sort the arrays according to the element values (< means descending)
                tmp = arrS(i): tmpN = arrN(1, i): tmp1 = arr1(1, i): tmp2 = arr2(1, i)
                arrS(i) = arrS(nxtEl): arrN(1, i) = arrN(1, nxtEl)
                     arr1(1, i) = arr1(1, nxtEl): arr2(1, i) = arr2(1, nxtEl)
                arrS(nxtEl) = tmp: arrN(1, nxtEl) = tmpN
                    arr1(1, nxtEl) = tmp1: arr2(1, nxtEl) = tmp2
            End If
        Next nxtEl
    Next i
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If you need the chart being dynamic, meaning to refresh it in case of any value changed in the referenced range (A1:D3, in your example), sheet `Change` event can be used. If a change in the above mentioned range, the event will call the above function. If need it, please copy the next code in the involved sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1:D3")) Is Nothing Then
        createStackedColChart_Arrays 'if need to change the Sub name, please adapt it here...
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

A more elaborated, dynamic version using all existing rows/columns in the sheet. The last column is calculated on the first row (column Headers):

```
Sub createStackedColChart_Arrays_Dynamic()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As String, arrN, arrSort
 Dim chartName As String, dict As Object, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of A:A column
 lastCol = Split(sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")(1) 'extract the last column Letter
 chartName = "MyChartSorted"
 
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create the necessary dictionary object
 For i = 2 To lastR
    dict.Add i - 1, sh.Range("A" & i & ":" & lastCol & i).value 'place in the dictionary the ranges to become chart series
 Next i
 
 arrN = sh.Range("A1:" & lastCol & 1).value    'X axes values (names array)
 
 'Create the reference array of summarized values per column:
 ReDim arrSort(1 To UBound(arrN, 2))
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrN, 2)
      For j = 1 To dict.count
            arrSort(i) = arrSort(i) + dict(j)(1, i) 'add each column value to summarize
      Next j
 Next i

 '_______________________________________________
 'Debug.Print Join(arrSort, "|"): Stop
 sortDArrs arrSort, arrN, dict  'sort the involved arrays (ranges) according to arrSort sorted descending

 'if the (testing) chart exists, delete it:
 On Error Resume Next
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartName).Delete
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 'create the necessary chart:
 With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=100, width:=375, top:=80, height:=225).Chart
    .Parent.Name = chartName                         'name it to have a reference when delete it
    
    For i = 1 To dict.count 'add a new series from the dictionary (sorted) items:
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Values = dict(i) 'add the series
    Next i
    
    .HasTitle = True                        'set it to allow a Title
    .chartTitle.text = "My Sorted Chart"    'set the Title
    .ChartType = xlColumnStacked            'set the chart type
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = arrN     'add values to X axis
 End With
End Sub

Sub sortDArrs(arrS, arrN, dict As Object)  'sort descending all involved arrays/ranges
    Dim i As Long, nxtEl As Long, tmp, tmpN, arrTemp, arrT, k As Long, j As Long
    ReDim arrTemp(dict.count - 1): ReDim arrT(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arrN, 2))

   For i = LBound(arrS) To UBound(arrS) - 1 'iterate between the arrS elements (except the last):
        For nxtEl = i + 1 To UBound(arrS)   'iterate between the arrS elements (starting from the second one):
            If arrS(i) < arrS(nxtEl) Then   'sort the arrays according to the element values (< means descending)
                tmp = arrS(i): tmpN = arrN(1, i) 'memorize the element temporaty walue
                For k = 0 To UBound(arrTemp): arrTemp(k) = dict(k + 1)(1, i): Next k 'do the same for each dictionary item
                arrS(i) = arrS(nxtEl): arrN(1, i) = arrN(1, nxtEl)
                For k = 1 To dict.count - 1      'the arrays content of a dictionary item cannot be changed directly!!!
                    arrT = dict(k): arrT(1, i) = dict(k)(1, nxtEl): dict(k) = arrT 'it cam be changed in this way
                Next k
                arrS(nxtEl) = tmp: arrN(1, nxtEl) = tmpN 'switch the array element value to the memorized one
                For k = 1 To dict.count          'do the same in each dictionary item array:
                    arrT = dict(k): arrT(1, nxtEl) = arrTemp(k - 1): dict(k) = arrT
                Next k
            End If
        Next nxtEl
    Next i
End Sub
```

The sheet `Change` event should have the necessary manually adapted. It can be automatically determined, but, in order to avoid running the code for each added header or value on the last row, a special cell should be also targeted and the event to skip the `Sub` running when the new range is added. Let us say the word "STOP". When deleted, everything should work as it should (automatically calculating the `lastR` and `LastCol` similarly as in the above code).

Comment: Your dynamic code is working so fast, But I don't understand why it does not work if I don't do `For i = 2 To lastR+2`. If I do `For i = 2 To lastR+1` The second series show #N/A. Did you test this code ?

Comment: Also, Why do you `Delete Chart` to create it again, isn't it better to do `.ChartArea.ClearContents`

Comment: Where did you find 'for i = 2 to lastR + 2'? It makes no sense. The code iterates between **existing rows**. Of course, I tested the code. It is complex and could not be finished without testing

Comment: the loop where you add Data in dictionnary

Comment: I made a code to create such a chart and then was simpler to delete it when testing. The code to update  the series is not complicated, but **different**. You did not ask about that. You din not even post your creation code, even if requested... I keft home and I do not have acces to a computer in the next two days.

Comment: Its fine no worries. Was just a kind question

Comment: Please, read the code again...